# Set style property of elements in a map loop in JSX in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Good day

I am busy teaching myself React for a new position I've recently started. I have a stupid question about syntax that I am unsure how to Google for.

The below code is from a project I am trying to help with whilst learning. I have managed to comprehend the broad strokes, as I have a fair amount of JavaScript experience.

I am trying to assign a top and left value for a graph that I am rendering on a map based on an x and y value I am getting from an object in an array that i am looping through with the map command.

From my research so far, you need to build up the object you are using for the style tag before you use it in your JSX. I only have access to the values in the objects I am looping through inside the loop, and am struggling to read these values into the preexisting object I am using for the style.

Previously defined object with default top and left values

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.chartStyle = { top: "15px", left: "15px" }
  }
```

Map loop where I need to change 'this.chartStyle' based on object data

```
this.props.data.data.map((d, i) => (
   <div key={"key"+i} style={this.chartStyle}>
       ...
   </div>
))
```

I've tried creating an object on the fly, or changing the variable inside the loop, but I'm getting compiler errors so I'm obviously doing it in the wrong place.

```
    this.props.data.data.map((d, i) => (
       <div key={"key"+i} style={top: d.y+"px, left: d.x}>
           ...
       </div>
    ))
...
    this.props.data.data.map((d, i) => (
       {this.chartStyle = {top: d.y+"px, left: d.x}}
       <div key={"key"+i} style={this.chartStyle}>
           ...
       </div>
    ))
```

I would be very grateful if someone could please help me understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for setting styles in React you need cover it in double curved brackets and styles have to be correct

```
    this.props.data.data.map((d, i) => (
   <div key={"key"+i} style={{top: d.y+"px", left: d.x+"px"}}>
       ...
   </div>
))
```